# Skin oranges 24-h in advance?

Tags: fruit, juice, oranges, juicing

I want to squeeze oranges quickly using the screw-type motorized juicers (e.g. Hurom). It would be good if I can have them pre-supremed and ready to be put in the juicer.

Will removing the rind of the oranges the night before maintain at least the flavor?

Answer (score 1):

No!! Not a good idea. The moment rand is removed. Oxidation starts to place. This will add more bitter to the fruit and when you rush the oranges into the machine. Your juice is definitely having that oxidized bitterness. Thumb rule, the moment you extract the juice it is ready to server or if not served immediately then you are betting on bitter taste.